# GTA V Beach Bum DLC won't show up in game on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I have a 360 which is connected via a poor internet connection. I have downloaded the Beach Bum DLC for GTA V and it is my understand it also works for single player offline.

I have installed it and in GTA V it is showing up as "Purchased" in Packs in the GTA V Pause menu tab "called Xbox Games Store".

I checked even the fake websites of san andreas autos in game and the Bifta car och the Beach Bums DLC is not showing up there as it should.

Does anyone know how you get the Beach Bum to work on Xbox 360 offline?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Beach Bum DLC is available offline as well.

According to a [post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634491-grand-theft-auto-v/68802056) it is most likely license issues with the xbox 360 (if you have a new console since you bought GTA V).

> My guess is that, like the majority of 360 owners, this isn't your first 360. Your license is still registered with the original 360 unit that you created your account on.
>
> 1. Make sure your 360 is online.
> 2. Access Account Management (last page of the XBOX guide menu).
> 3. Access License Transfer and activate it.
> 4. Delete and re-download any DLC media that you wish to access offline (you won't have to re-purchase your DLC).

Answer (score 0):

Gta 5 360 beach bum update does NOT work offline because you can only get certain things the dlc's are only for online only